# php - Continue nested foreach loops at the same time

Tags: php, foreach

I have two nested foreach loops:

```
$ren1 = array("class ConcreteClass1", "class hello");
$ren2 = array("class ConcreteClass2", "class bye");

    if(!empty($ren1) && !empty($ren2)){
        foreach($ren1 as $key1=>$value1){
            foreach($ren2 as $key2=>$value2){
                $result .= "Class renamed: ". $ren1[$key1]. " ==> ". $ren2[$key2]. "\n"; continue 2;
            } 
        }
    }
```

I use break and continue but they did not work.

What should I do to get desire output like this:

```
class ConcreteClass1 ==> class ConcreteClass2
class hello ==> class bye
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: where do you want to use your o/p in loop or outside loop

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish here but I suspect it's more an issue of restructuring your array to make it simpler to process.  For the record, you can't have "simultaneous" foreach loops, because that implies parallel execution and PHP is single-threaded unless you use a language extension like pthreads.  What you've got is nested foreach loops.  For each iteration of the outer loop the inner loop executes completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use nested loops:

```
$ren1 = array("class ConcreteClass1", "class hello");
$ren2 = array("class ConcreteClass2", "class bye");

if(!empty($ren1) && !empty($ren2)){
    foreach($ren1 as $key=>$value){
        echo "Class renamed: ". $ren1[$key]. " ==> ". $ren2[$key]. "\n";
    }
}
```

If the index between the arrays is always related to the other, just use that index on the second array.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code as follows:

```
foreach( $ren1 as $index => $value ) {
$result .= "Class renamed: ". $value. " ==> ". $ren2[$index]. "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

array1 and array2 are having two value. You write two nested foreach. So these nested foreach run 4 times (2 x 2).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you're not structuring your data in a format that will make parsing it as you want easy.  If you use a single associative array instead of multiple arrays per class you'll find your job is a lot easier.

```
$ren = [
    "ConcreteClass1" => "hello",
    "ConcreteClass2" => "bye",
];
$result = "";

foreach ($ren as $oldClass => $newClass) {
    $result .= "Class renamed: class {$oldClass} ==> class {$newClass}\n";
}
```

By the way, if you make sure $ren is always an array you don't need the !empty check.  A foreach on an empty array is essentially a no-op.